What episode had Butters cracking a safe?
Saw this in the opening bit to South Park, was curious which episode it was from (see below). It shows Butters taking a torch to a safe.


The episode City Sushi.  From the wiki :

In the episode, Butters is misdiagnosed with multiple personality
  disorder. Meanwhile, Tuong Lu Kim takes on South Park's new Japanese
  resident, who has put a sushi restaurant right next to his City Wok.

Relevant dialogue from the script:

Butters:  This is illegal. We could get arrested. [Dr. Janus breaks
  into some display cases and swipes the jewels into a satchel that
  Butters is carrying]. Oh Jesus!
Dr. Janus:    They're all idiots! The
  vault! Get to the vault! Come on! Go! Movie it!
[puts some welding
  goggles on Butters while getting a welding torch and firing it up] Get
  this on and get in that vault! That's where the real good are! * Torch that door, do you hear me?! I'll kill
  your parents! I'll kill your friends! I said get that fucking door
  open!
Butters:  I'm trying, sir! [this changes Dr. Janus' behavior]
Dr.
  Janus:  Butters? Butters, what are you doing? What is that? A
  blowtorch? Put that down! You're having another episode!
Butters:  What?
Dr. Janus:    Butters. Your name is Butters! Try and
  remember!

Picture from episode:

Just to clarify, he's breaking into the local bank vault - if you search for that instead of safe you'll get quite a few more results.
